# Force visual studio to have same include directories between debug and release mode

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, projects-and-solutions

I was wondering if there is a way to synchronize settings for include and link directories between debug and release configurations for project/solution?

More precisely, is there any way to tell visual studio I would like project properties

- C/C++ - > General -> "Additional Include Directories"
- Linker ->    General -> "Additional Library Directories"
- Linker -> Input ->    "Additional Dependencies"

to be same for debug and release configuration, or somehow efficiently/automatically  forward those settings from one configuration to the other configurations? Perhaps there is any plugin/script for that, since it is only necessary to change few lines in project text file to do what I want?

I'm currently using visual studio 2005, but I think this feature should not depend too much on version of the studio, so please post answers/solutions for any version of visual studio.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [property sheets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a4xbdz1e%28v=vs.80%29.aspx): create a property sheet containing the common properties, then include it in each build configuration. Do everything via the `Property Manager` window; be careful now: any change you want to make to the common properties must be made in the property sheet, not in the project properties!

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works! Out of curiosity, what happens if you change common property in the project properties - is this change ignored, or is it affecting only the project it has been made to?

Comment: it will affect only that project, and normally it will override what's in the property sheet